# T -SQL How to calc balance via T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the balance via T-SQL from this table

```
TID amount  balance
--- -----   -------
1    100   100
2    50    150
3    30    180
4    300   480
5    200   680
```

Can anyone please support me on this case?

Best regards.

Comment: show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

One way is using window function `sum`:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(amount) over (order by tid) balance
from your_table t;
```